# Handle Foreign languages in POST request in Spring MVC

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding

I am trying to handle save Foreign language words in DB in Spring MVC app, But it is not getting saved correctly. I used logger in Controller to check the values received in POST request, it is not showing the exact value that is being entered.

I am entering "Україна" and it is showing something weird like '╨г╨║╤?╨░╤?╨╜╨░' in controller using request.getParameter().

I found that if I add `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in my `<form>` tag then it is working perfectly fine because of the below code added in ApplicationContext,java file

```
@Bean(name = "multipartResolver")
 public CommonsMultipartResolver getMultipartResolver(){
  CommonsMultipartResolver commonsMultipartResolver = new CommonsMultipartResolver();
  commonsMultipartResolver.setMaxUploadSize(25000000);
  commonsMultipartResolver.setDefaultEncoding("utf-8");
  return commonsMultipartResolver;
 }
```

Is it possible to add `setDefaultEncoding("utf-8")` for non-multipart request.

Thanks in advance for your help. Please let me know if my question is not clear to you.

Comment: Set your project type to UTF-8. Also, if you have JSP's, you can set the encoding to UTF-8 there as well. If it's a saving problem. Check your table. Generally, where you see your table descriptiom, you can also see the encoding type, set it to UTF-8. Atleast in PgAdmin I can.

Comment: Have set the UTF-8 on jsp page. Also table is set to UTF-8. Can you please tell me how to set project to UTF-8. I am using JAVA config files instead web.xml.

Comment: Post your config. Do you use Maven, then add this in properties : `<project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>`.

Comment: I have already used this in my pom.xml file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved this issue by adding default encoding in my server. As I am using wildfly so added "default-encoding="UTF-8"" in standalone.xml file in `<servlet-container name="default">` tag.